# How can I remove a set of specific data, based on a condition, from a large dataset in R?

Tags: r, database, function, plyr, outliers

I have this dataset which includes all the sales for a company in a given year (company code = gvkey, year = fyearq, sales = saley), its sales growth rates(growth_rate_adjusted) (in regards to the past year) and the volatility of its growth rates. However, there are some outliers in this data set for certain years. In this case, I want to remove all rows for the year 1995 that have higher volatility than 3.0.

I have tried using ddplyr to filter it out in the following way

```
rs <-rs%>%
  filter(!fyearq == 1995 & !volatility > 3.0) %>%
  ungroup()
```

But that excludes all volatility above 4 for all years and excludes 1995 entirely from the dataset, which isn't my goal.

I would appreciate if someone could tell me how I can condition it to be only the volatility above 3.0 for the year 1995 specifically. I am unfortunately fairly new to R.

A sample with the data ordered by year for 1994 and 1995 (there will be some NA's, but they are ok) to make it reproducible:

```
structure(list(gvkey = c(65089L, 65090L, 65091L, 65094L, 65095L, 
65298L, 65351L, 65499L, 66430L, 66591L, 66624L, 109584L, 119053L, 
143972L, 145348L, 277918L, 1004L, 1009L, 1010L, 1011L, 1013L, 
1017L, 1019L, 1021L, 1025L, 1033L, 1034L, 1037L, 1038L, 1043L, 
1045L, 1048L, 1050L, 1055L, 1056L, 1072L, 1073L, 1075L, 1076L, 
1078L, 1082L, 1084L, 1086L, 1090L, 1094L, 1095L, 1097L, 1098L, 
1099L, 1104L, 1107L, 1108L, 1109L, 1111L), fyearq = c(1994L, 
1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 
1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 
1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 
1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 
1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 
1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L), growth_rate_adjusted = c(8.96928631198866, 
8.4280138706961, 9.02704614077282, 8.10147860671897, 7.85740916384215, 
10.7523572462577, 0.0325017896704669, 0.285143311711521, -0.0215766088784792, 
7.5140205008648, 10.4833287736384, 1.73691297130171, 0.117237940329646, 
1.34207225611898, 8.38865848733786, NA, 11.217767632108, -0.304963611388244, 
8.90548855887399, -0.465405529093955, 0.308162761266, -0.428463261697025, 
9.71621276929561, -0.272514090039389, 0.365258326126507, -0.835436753370402, 
10.6675419276932, 21.8645191343365, 0.172555503849585, -0.0528834362682823, 
9.77177091825209, -0.0617758053830246, 7.26998471225084, 10.2427038986383, 
0.174166169584557, 11.7224789811471, 5.10323576237965, -0.0390433072454226, 
8.410713700002, 10.0433658114349, 8.56357182841634, 13.2022040407414, 
11.9928308829399, 11.6432049346405, 0.117529642161838, 9.53135348756221, 
9.58048755435235, 0.0758862747892137, 0.0654783197588846, 9.49577594725737, 
10.4061554746601, -0.454122878475859, 12.2471344335624, 37.1728040342351
), volatility = c(2.55192643294808, 2.39434025265926, 2.56344451051799, 
2.30624765181967, 2.23928130844332, 3.04354720436549, NA, 0.402804266987728, 
0.358552136097001, 2.13611997423426, 2.98090959393336, NA, 0.0847119569693743, 
NA, 2.37661435221257, NA, 3.18081892321314, NA, 2.52968180517002, 
NA, 0.429862168272561, NA, 2.76287646243831, 0.454406152459777, 
NA, NA, 3.0077233808187, 6.17293600484418, 0.304536845392376, 
0.0411853414230726, 2.76986690678473, 0.157817595412998, 1.99372992450495, 
NA, 0.293215830307968, 3.24928278487391, NA, 0.342934649585831, 
2.35498186010912, 2.84022723248247, 2.40517143665036, 3.13067695078128, 
NA, NA, 0.326138274385994, 2.70848653980122, 2.74871785774601, 
NA, 0.299889508129728, 2.71608606652565, 2.94982624906776, NA, 
3.47847130692363, 10.490117417769)), row.names = c(NA, -54L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
rs <- rs[-which(rs$fyearq == 1995 & rs$volatility > 3), ]
```

Note that the opposite condition:

```
rs[which(rs$fyearq == 1995 & rs$volatility > 3), ]
```

returns 7 rows. Therefore we expect 54 - 7 = 47 rows if subsetting worked as desired.

Answer (score 1):

neilfws gave a correct base R solution. Here is a dplyr solution:

```
rs <- filter(rs, !(fyearq == 1995 & !is.na(volatility) & volatility > 3.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

We want to "remove all rows for the year 1995 that have higher volatility than 3.0".

We can filter to select everything where condition is `TRUE`, then negate the entire statement (instead of each individual component):

```
rs = rs%>%
  filter(!(fyearq == 1995 & volatility > 3.0)) %>%
  ungroup()

>rs
# A tibble: 36 x 4
   gvkey fyearq growth_rate_adjusted volatility
   <int>  <int>                <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 65089   1994               8.97        2.55 
 2 65090   1994               8.43        2.39 
 3 65091   1994               9.03        2.56 
 4 65094   1994               8.10        2.31 
 5 65095   1994               7.86        2.24 
 6 65298   1994              10.8         3.04 
 7 65351   1994               0.0325     NA    
 8 65499   1994               0.285       0.403
 9 66430   1994              -0.0216      0.359
10 66591   1994               7.51        2.14 
# … with 26 more rows
```

Comment: Not sure about this result. The TRUE condition `fyearq == 1995 & volatility > 3` returns 7 rows, so the desired result should have 47 rows, not 36 ?

Comment: @neilfws, yes you're right but I don't know why the code is producing this result. Any ideas?

Comment: @ NM_ The code is giving the wrong result because volatility is sometimes missing.

Comment: @ericOss I think there is another reason because it picks up some rows where volatility is `NA`. Just take a look at the output. Row 7 has a volatility of `NA`.

Comment: @ NM_ In row 7 the year is 1994. In your filter statement, R first evaluates the expression `(fyearq == 1995 & volatility > 3.0)` to see if it is true or false. If `fyearq` is 1994, the expression is false. If `fyearq` is 1995 and volatility is `NA` then the expression evaluates to `NA`, it's negation is also `NA` and the row does not meet the filter condition, but the OP's requirement is that it should.

Answer (score 0):

You'r already so close

```
rs <-rs%>%
  filter(!(fyearq == 1995 & volatility > 3.0)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Same issue as the answer by NM_.

Comment: The code is giving the wrong result because volatility is sometimes missing.